# Error changing Sensortag CC2650 Gyroscope sampling with android

Tags: android, gyroscope, texas-instruments

I'm trying to change the gyroscope sampling rate of a CC2650 SensorTag by android code but i'm getting an error.

As written in the CC2650 doc, the movement sensor rate can be changed in a range 100 ms - 2.55 sec

> Period    AA83*   R/W 1   Resolution 10 ms. Range 100 ms (0x0A) to 2.55 sec (0xFF). Default 1 second (0x64).
>   Here's of the code. It returns null writing characteristic.

This is my code. It returns null writing characteristic.

```
BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mGatt.getService(java.util.UUID.fromString("f000aa80-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"));
    if(mCustomService == null){
        Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
    return;
    }

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(java.util.UUID.fromString("f000aa83-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"));
    if (mWriteCharacteristic==null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to Find CHARACTERISTIC");
        return;
    }

    mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(new byte[] {0x0A});
    if(mGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic) == false){
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
    }
```

Thanks,
Federico.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/geobio/sensortag) project (especially on classes `GenericBluetoothProfile` and `SensorTagMovementProfile`).

Comment: Hi Andriy,
Thanks for your answer. I looked at the project and i think i'm doing the same in my code...but the method writeCharacteristc still returns null. Maybe i'm doing something wrong.